# What is a VGroup in manim?

Tags: manim

Could you explain to me what is a VGroup and how is it useful, please? I tried looking for it, but obviously to no avail, not much documentation there is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is basically a group of `VMobjects`. So say you have some equation consisting of multiple seperate `Texmobjects`. Then you want to move the entire thing. It would make sense to `VGroup` all the parts, so let `entire_eq = VGroup (eq_part1, eq_part2, eq_part3)` and then you would just have to move this `entire_eq`. This also applies for changing the colors, scaling and so fort.

This works for any kinds of `VMobject`.

Comment: Thank you. It's basicly like grouping in photoshop.

Comment: @TimSolnze exactly, that is what it is.